# React site using Material-UI has "excessive DOM size"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, material-ui

A quite simple React page / website (https://audio-converter.io) using material-ui has a huge DOM size: "1,393 elements" as reported by https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=https%3A%2F%2Faudio-converter.io%2F&hl=en_GB&tab=mobile.

I'm new at this.. there must be something I can improve: when I inspect the page in Chrome I see hundreds of `<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiTypography">...</style>` and `<style data-jss="" data-meta="MuiBox"> </style>` in the `<head>`.

Also, I'm wondering if, and hope that, a reduction of the DOM size might help reducing the "JavaScript execution time" which is quite long at 6.6 seconds (again as reported by Google's pagespeed)?

Comment: Please reproduce a simple version of your problem in a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) and include that code in your question.

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/16756